# Add dropshadow to an image with rounded corners on canvas with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas

My goal is to add load an image from an URL, make the edges round and add a drop shadow to the image.

In my code, I can successful make each of the steps separately work but together, the drop shadow is not added.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zfckwep8/1/

```
    // Load the image onto the canvas and apply rounded corners and shadow.
function addRoundedCornersWithShadow() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const image = new Image();
  image.src = 'https://picsum.photos/200/300'; 

  image.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    const cornerRadius = 20;
    const shadowBlur = 20;
    const shadowOffsetX = 5;
    const shadowOffsetY = 5;

    // Draw the shadow
    ctx.shadowBlur = shadowBlur;
    ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = shadowOffsetX;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = shadowOffsetY;

    // Draw the rounded rectangle with the image
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(cornerRadius, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width - cornerRadius, 0);
    ctx.arcTo(canvas.width, 0, canvas.width, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height - cornerRadius);
    ctx.arcTo(canvas.width, canvas.height, canvas.width - cornerRadius, canvas.height, cornerRadius);
    ctx.lineTo(cornerRadius, canvas.height);
    ctx.arcTo(0, canvas.height, 0, canvas.height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
    ctx.lineTo(0, cornerRadius);
    ctx.arcTo(0, 0, cornerRadius, 0, cornerRadius);
    ctx.closePath();

    // Clip the rounded rectangle
    ctx.clip();

    // Draw the image on the canvas with rounded corners and shadow
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Clear the shadow for future drawings (optional)
    ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
  };
}

addRoundedCornersWithShadow();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the clipping region will also clip the shadow, and so you won't be able to see it.

For a simple case as yours, where you are drawing an image, you can create a `CanvasPattern` from your image, and `fill()` your path with that pattern. This way you avoid the need for `clip()` and the shadow can be painted. However you'll face another issue, since you do set your canvas size to the image's size, the shadow will be cut. To fix this, you need to set your canvas width and height to the image's size more twice the shadow-blur and once the shadow-offset.
Then you'll need to center your path, and since we're using a `CanvasPattern`, whose position is always relative to the context's current transform, the best to do so is to `translate()` your context.

```js
async function addRoundedCornersWithShadow() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const image = new Image();
  image.src = 'https://picsum.photos/200/300'; 
  await image.decode();  

  const cornerRadius = 20;
  const shadowBlur = 20;
  const shadowOffsetX = 5;
  const shadowOffsetY = 5;

  canvas.width = image.width + (shadowBlur * 2) + shadowOffsetX;
  canvas.height = image.height + (shadowBlur * 2) + shadowOffsetY;


  // We'll use a CanvasPattern to draw our image
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(image, "no-repeat");

  // Prepare the shadow
  ctx.shadowBlur = shadowBlur;
  ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = shadowOffsetX;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = shadowOffsetY;

  // Place our drawing so that we can see the full shadow
  ctx.translate(shadowBlur - shadowOffsetX, shadowBlur - shadowOffsetY);
  // Trace the rounded rectangle (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/roundRect)
  ctx.roundRect(0, 0, image.width, image.height, cornerRadius);

  // Draw the image on the canvas with rounded corners and shadow
  ctx.fill();

  // Clear the shadow and fillStyle for future drawings (optional)
  ctx.resetTransform();
  ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
}

addRoundedCornersWithShadow();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Now, this works because you only wanted to draw an already existing image. If you wanted to use the clipping region to draw a more complex graphic made of a few drawing commands, that wouldn't be the best solution.

In such a case, what can be done is to draw the shadow with a huge offset, so that what should have been painted on the canvas is actually painted outside, and that only the shadow remains where expected:

```js
function addRoundedCornersWithShadow() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const width = 300;
  const height = 200;
  const cornerRadius = 20;
  const shadowBlur = 20;
  const shadowOffsetX = 5;
  const shadowOffsetY = 5;

  canvas.width = width + (shadowBlur * 2) + shadowOffsetX;
  canvas.height = height + (shadowBlur * 2) + shadowOffsetY;

  // So that we can clean up after we draw (optional)
  ctx.save();
  // We'll need to remove the clipping region during the drawing (required)
  ctx.save();
  
  // Trace the rounded rectangle (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/roundRect)
  const roundRect = new Path2D();
  roundRect.roundRect(shadowBlur + shadowOffsetX, shadowBlur + shadowOffsetY, width, height, cornerRadius);
  
  // Clip the context
  ctx.clip(roundRect);

  // Draw some stuff
  for (let i = 0; i<120; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = `#${((Math.random()*0xFFFFFF)|0).toString(16).padStart(6, "0")}`;
    ctx.roundRect(Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height, Math.random()*width/2, Math.random()*height/2, 12);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.beginPath();
  }
  
  // Remove the clipping region (required)
  ctx.restore();
  
  // Prepare the shadow
  ctx.shadowBlur = shadowBlur;
  ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  // Note that we add the canvas width to the offset
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = shadowOffsetX + canvas.width;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = shadowOffsetY;
  // Set the context to draw behind the current content
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
  // If you wish to use the current content as the source for the shadow,
  // Redraw the canvas over itself, but in the non visible area
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, -canvas.width, 0);
  // If you wanted to use the roundRect instead you'd have done
  // ctx.translate(-canvas.width, 0);
  // ctx.fill(roundRect);

  // Clean up for future drawings (optional)
  ctx.restore();
}

addRoundedCornersWithShadow();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: @Kaiido In the above code, what if I want to control which corner is not to be rounded? the roundRec makes every corner round, what if I just want to have the bottom two rounded and not the top two?

Comment: @DarwinSwartz you can specify every four corners independently (and even every 8 ellipse's arc independently), just like in CSS border-radius if you're more used to it. So to set the bottom two only that'd be `roundRect(x, y, w, h, [0, 0, rad, rad])` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/roundRect

Comment: @Kaiido, Thank you so much Kaiido for guiding me on it, recently I saw on Figma that we can have IOS-style rounded corners, i.e. more smooth corners, is there any way to achieve the level of smoothness in canvas?